# css conflicate with mozilla

Tags: html, css

my css does work correctly in chrome like [image](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-10/60940806530695990028.png) 
but it doesn't work in Waterfox like  [image](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-10/43285855895623177838.png)
what can I do?

```
.form-control {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
        transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }



    form-group input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
        float: right;
        direction: rtl;
    }
```

Comment: try adding `form-group textarea {float:right}`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes you could put it as an answer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of the float left for input fields the issue was coming

```
form-group input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

you can fix it by giving `float:left` for `textarea`

```
form-group textarea {float:right}
```